# How do I refactor my servlet to take advantage of dependency injection?

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.33 with Java 6.  I have this servlet ...

```
public class SaveXmlServlet extends HttpServlet {

private CacheService cacheService;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    cacheService = CacheServiceLocator.cacheService();
}   // init
```

How can I redesign my servlet to ...

1. Take advantage of dependency injection so that a mocking framework like mockito can inject its own "cacheService" implementation
2. Guarantee that there is only one instance of cacheservice in my jvm.  Right now the line "CacheServiceLocator.cacheService()" guarantees this.

?  I'm not using (or allowed to use) frameworks like Spring or Guice.  Grateful for any thoughts on refactoring this.  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: *"I'm not using (or allowed to use) frameworks like Spring or Guice."* Well, reinvent one yourself. They are open source, so that you can get some insights. But... How does reinventing the wheel make sense? I'd concentrate on solving the "I'm not allowed" problem. That's much bigger than your current problem.

Comment: But technical problems are so much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options, although I recommend smacking someone for not "letting" you use a framework. Two quickies; I'm sure there are others. I'd go the smacking route first.

You can mock static classes using a combination of EasyMock/Mockito and, say, PowerMock. Technically you don't need to change anything at all to get the in-test behavior you want.

A class name provided by a servlet init parameter or JNDI resource could be used to create an instance of the cache locator. Providing a setter for the same allows a unit/etc. test to set it on the class.

Comment: Regarding, "A class name provided by a servlet init parameter or JNDI resource could be used to create an instance of the cache locator", could you provide a code sample b/c I'm not seeing it yet.  Also, I don't care about CacheServiceLocator per se, as long as I can control how the "cacheService" member field is set in my JUnit test vs my normal application.  Thanks,  -

Comment: @Dave ... Not sure what else I can add, use a string class name to create a new instance of the implementation in the "live" system, use a setter in the test.

Comment: Oh, that's clear now ... I forgot the use of class instantiation through the Class.forName method (or whatever that was).  Your solution is greatly appreciated, -

Comment: @Dave Ah, gotcha. No problem; hope it helps. Or at least doesn't make anything worse ;)